# Stored procedure with static data not returning values

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, model-view-controller

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetReportLevel]
AS
    DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (BK_REPORT_LEVEL INT, REPORT_LEVEL_NAME VARCHAR(MAX))

    INSERT INTO @temp 
    VALUES (0, 'Client Group'), (1, 'Client'), (2, 'Related Matter'), (3, 'Matter')

    SELECT * 
    FROM @TEMP 
GO
```

The entity database like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<usp_GetReportLevel_Result> usp_GetReportLevel()
    {
        //const string storedProcedure = "usp_GetReportLevel";

        var result = Database.SqlQuery<usp_GetReportLevel_Result>($"EXEC usp_GetReportLevel");
        return result;
    }
```

The usp_GetReportLevel_Result as this:

```
public class usp_GetReportLevel_Result
{
    [Column("BK_REPORT_LEVEL")]
    public int BK_REPORT_LEVEL;
    [Column("REPORT_LEVEL_NAME")]
    public string REPORT_LEVEL_NAME;
}
```

and the c# code in a constructor to select the list items from the stored procedure as this section:

```
    List<SelectListItem> reportLevelList2= new List<SelectListItem>();

    var reportLevelusp = context.usp_GetReportLevel();

    foreach (var reportLevel in reportLevelusp)
    {
        SelectListItem lvl = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = reportLevel.REPORT_LEVEL_NAME,
            Value = reportLevel.BK_REPORT_LEVEL.ToString()
        };
        reportLevelList2.Add(lvl);
    }

    ReportLevelList = reportLevelList2;
```

Now if I debug that code, the `foreach` will enter 4 times, telling me that it is reading the database values right, but the values `BK_REPORT_LEVEL` and `REPORT_LEVEL_NAME` are always 0 and null respectively.

Why is this happening? The stored procedure is returning what I want to expect if I execute it on the database, Why `Linq` isn't getting the correct data? I can't see the error

[image]

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the start of your procedure, does that help?

Comment: @DavidG no, still returning 0 and null

Comment: I assume you added it before the `INSERT` but after the `AS`?

Comment: I try it after the `AS `and after the `DECLARE @TEMP TABLE`, neither worked

Comment: How about removing the temp table completely. It's probably better anyway to do `SELECT 1 AS BK_REPORT_LEVEL, 'Client' AS REPORT_LEVEL_NAME UNION SELECT 2, 'Related Matter' UNION  SELECT 3, 'Matter'`

Comment: Though this should really be in a table, not in a stored proc.

Comment: Yeah, is giving me much trouble, I think I will change that info on a table. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have a case sensitive collation? Don't mix 'temp' and 'Temp'.

Comment: No, I don't have sensitive collation

Comment: EXEC dbo.usp_GetReportLevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't have to change anything, all was all right. I just needed to add `{ get; set; }` on the variables....

```
public class usp_GetReportLevel_Result
{
    [Column("BK_REPORT_LEVEL")]
    public int BK_REPORT_LEVEL { get; set; }
    [Column("REPORT_LEVEL_NAME")]
    public string REPORT_LEVEL_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with Selecting from Temp tables or table variables from SQL SP's before.  Depends on what version of SQL Server you are dealing with.  You need to use with result set:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2356/overview-of-with-result-sets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/

Convert your call to use this:

```
EXEC usp_GetReportLevel
WITH RESULT SETS
(
 ( 
  BK_REPORT_LEVEL INT, 
  REPORT_LEVEL_NAME varchar(max)
 ) 
)
```

Comment: Assuming that you referred changing the entity database procedure to make a call like that, it is still returning the same values. If you mean changing anything else, I haven't try it yet.

Comment: also, this is the info of the sql server: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17230.0

Answer (score 0):

Try ExecuteSqlCommand:

```
  _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myproc");
```

Or with a return parameter:

```
 SqlParameter stmt = new SqlParameter("@stmt", System.Data.SqlDbType.Varchar);
 stmt.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("myproc @stmt out", stmt);
 var qry = stmt.value;
```

Make sure to put the out parameter in the procedure as well.

Comment: @Ragmar how about ToList(); like:

var result = Database.SqlQuery<usp_GetReportLevel_Result>($"EXEC usp_GetReportLevel").ToList();